# How can I list all the clusters using k8s java library

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubectl

I want to access the k8s configuration api through a java client or any other supported language.
How can I do these kubectl commands using k8s-client :

`kubectl config get-contexts`

`kubectl config use-context foo`

Comment: As you've said: `any other supported language`, I'd reckon you could check the Python equivalents: [1](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/multiple_clusters.py), [2](https://kubeconfig-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Please tell if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kubectl config get-contexts:

```
loadConfig().getContexts();
```

kubectl config use-context foo:

```
KubeConfig config = loadConfig();
config.setContext("foo");
```